# Why does my submit button act as a pagerefresher?

Tags: php, html, sql

This code is supposed to update my table, but it just refreshes the page. The query works, i tested it. its the submit button but i dont know why>

```
if(isset($_POST['nameupdate']))
                            {
                                echo('<hr>');
                                echo('Vul nieuwe waarde in');
                                $did = $jnm;
                                echo "<form method='post' data-ajax='false' action=''>";
                                echo "<input type='text' name='nmbox' value='".$did."'>";
                                echo "<input type='submit' name='nmupdate' value='Update'>";
                                echo "</form>";
                                if(isset($_POST['nmupdate']))
                                {
                                    $opm = $_POST['nmbox'];
                                    $query = "UPDATE users SET name = '$opm' WHERE username = '$jus'";
                                    $stm = $con->prepare($query);
                                    $stm->execute();
                                    header("location:decdprofileedit.php");
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Why so many buttons - `nameupdate`, `nmupdate`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put nested if statement outside the first if statement